# Remove pystray icon from outside of pystray menu

Tags: python, tkinter, pystray

I have tkinter app which I am trying to add pystary icon. I just implemented it successfully. But I want to call "show window" method from another class not only from the menu item of pystray. But in order to do that I have to pass icon parameter. How can I call this method from outside?

```
def hide_window():
    root.withdraw()
    image = Image.open("statics/icon.ico")
    menu = (item('Open App', show_window), item('Exit', quit_window))
    icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "Tax Status Checker", menu)
    icon.run()


def show_window(icon):
    icon.stop()
    root.deiconify()


def quit_window(icon):
    icon.stop()
    root.destroy()
```

I don't know how to approach or change code structure.